# Move V2 (ARM) virtual machines between azure subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to move a virtual machine (ARM) between subscriptions.

With V1 machines the process was straight forward.

- shut down machine
- copy vhd to storage account in new subscription
- mark vhd as boot drive
- create VM in new subscription using this boot drive

I have tried to create a new ARM virtual machine and replace the vhd file, but this does not work as the vhd blob has a lease even when the machine is shut down.

Is there a way using PowerShell to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "test" -VhdUri $uri -CreateOption attach -Windows
```

Wrapped into the rest of a [VM Create script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603754.aspx)

Comment: I will test this and report back